# Opencv3.1.0 findHomography returns empty matrix

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

I am now working on an image registration problem.

I am using the findHomography function of opencv3.1.0 to get homography. The problem is that I always get an empty matrix even if with different images. 
I tried different feature descriptors, like ORB, BRISK. This happens only for ORB. But I have to use ORB.

So... why do I get an empty matrix? And how can I get a good homography matrix? Thank you:)

```
Ptr<ORB> ptrORB = ORB::create(2000);
ptrORB->detect(img1, kpts1);           //use ORB as detector
ptrORB2->detect(img2, kpts2);

Ptr<BRISK> ptrBrisk = BRISK::create(); //use BRISK as descriptor
ptrBrisk->compute(img1, kpts1, desp1);
ptrBrisk->compute(img2, kpts2, desp2);

//Nearest neighbour ratio matching
double ratio = 0.8;
vector<vector<DMatch>> nnMatches;
vector<DMatch> matches;
BFMatcher matcher;
matcher.knnMatch(desp1, desp2, nnMatches, 2);
for (int k = 0; k < nnMatches.size(); k++) {
    if (nnMatches[k][0].distance / nnMatches[k][1].distance < ratio) {
        matches.push_back(nnMatches[k][0]);
    }
} 

//Homography
std::vector<Point2f> points1;
std::vector<Point2f> points2;

for (int i = 0; i < matches.size(); i++) {
    points1.push_back(kpts1[matches[i].queryIdx].pt);
    points2.push_back(kpts2[matches[i].trainIdx].pt);
}

Mat H = findHomography(points1, points2, RANSAC);
```

Comment: Would it be possible for you to post the code snippets so that we can investigate what's the problem?

Comment: Hi, I post my code below. For the image, you can find an image with high resolution. Thank you.

Comment: what's the size of points1 and points2?

Comment: It's 291 for both. But the keypoints are not well distributed. With ORB, it's common to get several keypoints at a position.